# why is the jquery regular expression producing wierd result

Tags: javascript, jquery

i tried to replace a text string using the jquery regular expression, instead am texts are multiplying by 4 instead of just replacing the match.

code:

```js
var $div = $('#container div');
$div.text($div.text().replace(/division/ig, 'div'));
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div>this is the first division element</div>
  <div>this is the second division element</div>
  <div>this is the third division element</div>
  <div>this is the fourth division element</div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

From what i saw in a material, this code should work fine. But somehow it is not producing the expected results.Could someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: jQuery doesn't have regular expressions. JavaScript does.

Comment: Your code says "take the text in *all* `div`s, apply regex, set the result in *each* `div`".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use a loop, or a callback function, because you're having multiple elements.

```
$('#container div').text(function(i, text) {
    return text.replace(/division/ig, 'div');
});
```

[jQuery.text() documentation.](http://api.jquery.com/text/#text-function)

Example:

```js
$('#container div').text(function(i, text) {
    return text.replace(/division/ig, 'div');
});
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div>this is the first division element</div>
  <div>this is the second division element</div>
  <div>this is the third division element</div>
  <div>this is the fourth division element</div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: how so?, what i followed is a  code i saw on a jquery ebook

Comment: But your code is not working and mine does. @pedroyanky ;) Show us the ebook then.

Comment: i think it is one jquery succinctly or so, i downloaded the pdf

Comment: But please can you tell me what ever is wrong with my code?

Comment: Yes, sure. As already said in the comments under your question, your script get *all text* at once, and then set the text out of all `divs` back to each single `div`. Thats because you will have all texts in each `div` afterwards ... I hope you understand what I mean. ;) @pedroyanky

Comment: thanks alot well understood. But a final note, in such a case where there is more than one elements, i have to do iteration right?

Comment: An iteration, or a callback like in my example. Yes. @pedroyanky

Comment: thank you so much, i think will learn more about callbacks then.

Comment: sorry, i do understand the iteration, but the callback, the parameter passed to the function(i, text) i seems lost. please can you shed some light on that?

Comment: I posted a link to the documentation in my answer. This should tell you anything about that. ;) @pedroyanky

Answer (score 1):

You can loop over each `div` element using `$(...).each` like:

```
var $div = $('#container div');
$div.each(function() {
  var text = $(this).text().replace(/division/ig, 'div');
  $(this).text(text);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var $div = $('#container div');
$div.each(function(index, value){
  $(this).text($(this).text().replace(/division/ig, 'div'));
});
```

Comment: Execute it and you will see. ;)

Comment: oh that because of typo my bad :(

Answer (score -1):

As mentioned, you need to loop over each element that has been selected. You can do this in jquery:

```
$('#container div').each(function(idx) {
  $( this ).text(function(i, text) {
     return text.replace(/division/ig, 'div');
  });
});
```

Comment: Why loop AND callback?

Comment: why the downvote? @eisbehr I wasn't aware that .text() callback will operate on a set of matched elements. Having said that, my solution will still work :)

Comment: Because things work it doesn't mean they are correct. And your example is really *bad practice*.

Comment: why is this bad practice? There may be a use case where someone may want to do a prior operation on the selected element before replacing the text?